# Triggers error 1064

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, phpmyadmin

- Question 1: I get several database for each website on one server. When a user is created, I want to replicate is data to all database. Is it good to do with **triggers sql with phpadmin** ?
- Question 2: Did I miss something in my request ?

**My request :**

```
CREATE TRIGGER `wordpress_database1`.`insert_user_from_database2` AFTER INSERT ON `wordpress_database2`.`wp_users`
FOR EACH
ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO `wordpress_database1`.`wp_users` (
ID,
user_login,
user_pass,
user_nicename,
user_email,
user_url,
user_registered,
user_activation_key,
user_status,
display_name
)
VALUES (
New.ID, New.user_login, New.user_pass, New.user_nicename, New.user_email, New.user_url, New.user_registered, New.user_activation_key, New.user_status, New.display_name
);
END;$$
```

**I get this error with phpadmin sql:**

```
#1435 - Trigger in wrong schema
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have not ended the trigger,

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `wordpress_database1`.`insert_user_from_database2` 
AFTER INSERT ON `wordpress_database2`.`wp_users`
FOR EACH
ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `wordpress_database1`.`wp_users` ( ID, user_login, user_pass, user_nicename,  user_email, user_url, user_registered, user_activation_key, user_status, display_name)
    VALUES ( New.ID, New.user_login, New.user_pass, New.user_nicename, New.user_email, New.user_url, New.user_registered, New.user_activation_key, New.user_status, New.display_name );
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: i correct by adding the ended. what but does #1435 - Trigger in wrong schema mean ?

Comment: actually I didn't try this but I guess it is not possible to allow access trigger from one database into another (*NOT REALLY SURE*)

Comment: So have you get any idea of how i can transfer a table of database1 to database2 ?